# Justify an element with the edge of the screen (without changing markup)

Tags: html, css

Given markup like this:

```
<div>
  <p>blah blah</p>
  <img src="...">
  <p>blah blah</p>
</div>
```

Is there a convenient way to float the `img` all the way to the right or left side of the *screen* (which may be different from the right or left edge of the containing div?)

I understand there are lots of ways to do this that involve changing the markup, but I'm interested in finding a way with no change (or very little change) to the markup.  This would be something like `position: fixed; right: 0` - but keeping the element in the flow, and not affecting the *vertical* positioning.

Comment: You mean `position: fixed`, not `display: fixed`?

Comment: Wouldn't you just use `position: absolute; /*or fixed*/` with `float: left; /*or right*/`?

Comment: I'm not aware of any way to do that with pure CSS while keeping the element in the flow. You could probably pull it off using `position: relative` and some javascript, though.

Comment: @gcbenison did you check my answer here?

Answer (score 0):

If you know the left padding&margin of the container you can use `translateX`:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
div {
  margin-left: 150px;
  padding-left: 25px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
div img {
  transform: translateX(-175px);
  opacity: 0.75;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>blah blah</p>
  <img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff">
  <p>blah blah</p>
</div>
```